# sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev : The following packages have unmet dependencies: libpcre2-dev

Tags: linux, flutter

for new flutter 3.0 installation on linux requires libgtk-3-dev

When i try `sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev` following dependencies error getting.

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcre2-dev : Depends: libpcre2-8-0 (= 10.39-3build1) but 10.39-3+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+2 is to be installed
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, Still issue is there

Comment: You must downgrade the `libpcre2-8-0` to version `10.39-3build1` with `sudo apt-get install libpcre2-8.0=10.39-3build1` and then install `sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need downgrade the `libpcre2-8-0` to version `10.39-3build1` :

`sudo apt-get install libpcre2-8.0=10.39-3build1`

And then install `libgtk-3-dev`:

`sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev`